# Can we use git gui for windows as well as git bash (command line interface) to push code into remote repository

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I started off using Git bash command line interface to push code into github repository (remote). i came across git gui interface and I feel more comfortable using it. so I installed it. can I use git gui to push code into existing repository? does it cause any problems to start using git guid application for repositories where code was pushed using git bash?

thanks much
kind regards
nath

Comment: Not at all.  You can use them interchangeably

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - there should be no issues whatsoever. I use both all the time, and encounter no issues.